# Directory API / Gmail API

Tags: google-api, gmail, google-workspace

is there any way to manage gmail user settings (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) for all userids within a gsuite domain? The boilerplate works great for userid 'me' but I would like to to do it my whole list of gmail accounts.

I tried to enable delegation from directory API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) but how do I link the right with the gmail API ? 
Do I still have to go throught restricted oauth2 so I cannot do it without the users consent?

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution it is called GAM which is a great helper tool to set your directory API keys and provides cli to manage the gmail settings of the users

https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/ExamplesEmailSettings#retrieving-a-signature